# record(forDuration:) method stops on its own

Tags: ios, swift

I just want to verify whether the method record(forDuration:) will record the audio for this specified amount of time and then stop the recording on its own without me calling explicitly stop(), is this correct?

```
func startRecording(){

        do{
            let audioURL = self.getAudioURL()
             print("first \(audioURL)")
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url:self.getAudioURL(),settings:settings)
            audioRecorder.delegate = self
            audioRecorder.record(forDuration: 15)
        }catch{
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see below from documentation:

> Declaration
>
> func record(forDuration duration: TimeInterval) -> Bool
>
> Parameters duration The maximum duration, in seconds, for the
>   recording.
>
> Return Value true if successful, otherwise false.
>
> Discussion
>   **The recorder stops when the duration of recorded audio reaches the value in the duration parameter.**